# Servicestack server events

Tags: c#, events, stack, server

currently messing up with events, on the server side (self host). But in official documentation nothing shown regarding how to invoke events, which one will be forwarded to client... can somebody give me a hand? Maybe a simple example, or something, please?

Answer (score 6):

The reasons for supporting Server Sent Events you need to do following steps:

Server Sent Events (SSE) is an elegant web technology for efficiently receiving push notifications from any HTTP Server. It can be thought of as a mix between long polling and one-way WebSockets and contains many benefits over each:

1. Simple - Server Sent Events is just a single long-lived HTTP Request
   that any HTTP Server can support
2. Efficient - Each client uses a single TCP connection and each message avoids the overhead of HTTP    Connections and Headers
   that's often faster than Web Sockets.
3. Resilient - Browsers automatically detect when a connection is broken    and automatically reconnects
4. Interoperable - As it's just plain-old    HTTP, it's introspectable with your favorite HTTP Tools and even    works
   through HTTP proxies (with buffering and checked-encoding    turned
   off).
5. Well Supported - As a Web Standard it's supported in all major browsers except for IE which can be enabled with polyfills.

   i.e. it's an beautifully simple and elegant Web Standard with a better HTTP fidelity than WebSockets, that's perfect fit for Server Push Communications that works in both ServiceStack' ASP.NET and SelfHosts without requiring any extra .NET dependencies or require the host Windows Server have WebSockets support enabled to use. IE Support can be enabled with polyfills.

   WebSockets may be supported at a later date but that's likely to require additional external dependencies and requirements for a Windows Server that supports WebSockets.

Comment: does it make sense for you...?
or you want Support for Authenticating with ServerEventsClient..?

Comment: second one, already got ServerEventsClient on the client side